# Stop Android Process from Web App

Tags: java, android, process

I'm working on an Android app that communicates with a web app and I need help figuring out how to stop a process in the Android app from the web app. I need to allow the user of the web app to simply click a button which will stop a process within the android app. Any ideas on how to do this? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Edit: I'm using JavaScript for my web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can call native Android code from `WebView`. This means that you can call whatever function you want of your Adnroid app from within your Web app. See this:

**Calling native code from within web view:** 
When creating the web view add javascript interface (basically java class whose methods will be exposed to be called via javascript in the web view).

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

The definition of the javascript interface class itself (this is examplary class I took from another answer of mine and opens video in native intent)

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
        this.activity = activiy;
    }

    public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoAddress), "video/3gpp"); // The Mime type can actually be determined from the file
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now if yo want to call this code form the html of the page you provide the following method:

```
<script>
  function playVideo(video){
    window.JSInterface.startVideo(video);
  }
</script>
```

So you need to add the appropriate method to `JSInterface` and call the code from within the Web App.

Comment: Right now, I have a button that sends GPS coordinates to a database and then a web app displays the user's location in real time. I need to allow the web app user to stop the Android app from sending coordinates, so is there a way to do this without webview? Or can I implement a portion of the app in webview and still allow the button to run Android functions. Sorry, I'm a bit confused and I hope I don't have to re do my entire app. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... I have assumed that the Android App accesses the Web App through a web view. Now things have changed. If I get it correctly you have two totally irrelated apps and you want the Web App to send information to the android app?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. I'm new to Android and it's something I hadn't considered until now. I'm going to have to open some line of communication between the Android app and the web app and I'd like to stay away from using a WebView if possible. The Android app just sends coordinates with a unique ID to a database and then the web app pulls from that database. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could I start an activity after the button is pressed (the button that starts tracking) that has a webview layout which calls a JS program saying something like "You are being tracked." and then use that channel to call a function (from the JS program) in a different class (in the Android app) to stop the tracking?

Comment: Nope. In your case web view / javascript will not work. You can not invoke javascript client side remotely from the web app. What you need is a remote procedure call. However, the problem is that you can not count on fixed ip for the phone, so opening a socket client side is also not an option. Best choice is to go with android push notifications (see here http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html), but keep in mind that such kind of notification sending is not instantenious.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that the app will invoke a different JS program (in web view) that will update the status of the tracking and then the web app (we'll call it JS program one) can cancel the tracking for the specific user. When the tracking begins, the app will send the user id to the JS program (JS program two) and serve as an intermediary between the Android app and the web app (program one). Program one will call a function in program two, which will call the app and stop the tracking. Seems like quite a work around but I'm running out of time to finish this. Do you think that will work?

Comment: However this way you will need to keep a web view all the time in your application. Actually why don't you just implement subscriber listener: you open a port on the side of your web app and you listen to it from your Android application. When time comes you send a stopping notification. This might happen to be quite resource consuming (especially speaking of internet connection/ battery), but at least is quick fix for people that run out of time.

Comment: You bring up a good point with the web view always needing to be active. Know of any good tutorials on how to implement a subscriber listener?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8394/discussion-between-alex-and-boris-strandjev)

Comment: Actually I used incorrect term here, probably. My idea was to open connection to the Web app via socket. This tutorial should prove useful to you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html. Just open the socket in service (so you do not block UI):  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html